# What exactly was Spock doing that caused his death?

Tags: star-trek, spock, the-wrath-of-khan

What exactly was Spock doing in *Star Trek: The Wrath of Khan* that caused his death?

Answer (score 13):

## He was trying to correct a problem with the warp core

You will remember that Khan engaged the *Enterprise* in battle; this severely damaged the *Enterprise*, including the Warp Core.  The *Enterprise* needed warp drive to escape the explosion of the Genesis device.  Consequently (and as per [Memory Alpha's description](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spock#Death_and_resurrection)):

> Spock sacrificed his own life by **repairing the Enterprise's plasma conduits – in a severely irradiated portion of engineering** – in order to save the crew.

Comment: And in J.J. Abrams "remake" in the new timeline, it is Kirk who corrects the core and gets killed.

Comment: Spoilers, @Thomas !

Comment: That movie was spoiled before they filmed the first scene.